# python - how to make autocomplete gui?

Tags: python, user-interface

I searched so much but I couldn't find what I should use so I tried to use the built-in Tkinter but I can't find how to make what I want to make with it.

I want to have a text entry where user types something and my program makes some dynamic suggestions by opening a dropdown menu and user can choose the top option by pressing enter or they can click on one of the options or use up/down keys. and then that option will be added to a large text box under that single line textbox.

Can you recommend me any toolkit for python that I can make this GUI with? Also a link to a good tutorial for that toolkit would be much appreciated bc I'm new to python GUI.

Actually since this is very useful I'm sure there must be some snippet out there that would do this! But I can't find it yet!

Sorry if my question is a little too broad. But I'm so exhausted from searching to no avail. So I thought maybe some experienced people can easily help me out.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. See [https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check out [this](https://github.com/Coal0/Utilities/tree/master/tkinter_autocomplete) module, which does exactly what you want (**disclaimer: I am the author of that code**).

Specifically, the code is not a `tkinter.Entry` widget, but a 'wrapper' (`tk.Frame`) around a `tkinter.Entry` and a `tkinter.Listbox` widget, the latter of which displays the results in an ordered list. If you want to redesign this behaviour yourself, I highly recommend using a similar approach rather than packing one widget below the other.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [link](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming) you have a lot of choices.

- [PyGTK](http://www.pygtk.org/)
- [PyQt](https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro)
- [wxPython](https://www.wxpython.org/)